# Eve-teasing... are such words used only in the country of origin

Tags: word-choice, expressions, dialects, gender-politics

I was reading a newspaper published in Indonesia and while quoting sexual harassment , the term 'eve-teasing" was repeatedly used.

> E.g. The Bontang police arrested two residents for eve-teasing,
> beating *and* threatening a minor girl at...

I looked in the **Oxford dictionary** which provides the following:

> Definition of eve-teasing in English:noun [mass noun] **Indian**
>
> The  making of unwanted sexual remarks or advances by a man to a woman
> in a  public place.

My question(s):

- Is it that such words are only used in the country of origin or neighboring countries
- Do such words (read-Indian) find a place in AmE and BrE writings too
- What is the equivalent to eve-teasing in AmE and BrE
- Any anti-women connotations?

Answer (score 12):

[Eve-teasing is a **euphemism** used in India.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_teasing)
(Wiki)

A similar example is "ragging"- In the Indian sub-continent, “[ragging](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ragging)” is actually the bullying of new college students.

> In the Indian term “eve-teasing,” the word “eve” alludes to the
>   biblical story of Eve tempting Adam to stray from the path of
>   righteousness.

*An Oxford English Dictionary definition for “teasing” is “to tempt someone sexually with no intention of satisfying the desire aroused*.

- Both parts of the term put the blame on the woman
- terms enter a language with exposure to foreign culture.
- to me, it does not appear to be an agreeable word for a disagreeable
  act.
- common expressions (orthophemism) are: sexual harassment and molestation

Answer (score 7):

> Is it that such words are only used in the country of origin or neighboring countries

"Such words" suggests you mean "and other words like it", and I don't know just what you would consider "such words". It's true that this particular phrase is largely confined to India and its neighbours. To the extent its used outside, it is used in considering whether (and if so in what way) such harassment there differs from harassment in other cultures.

> Do such words (read-Indian) find a place in AmE and BrE writings too

There are words of Indian origin in English outside of India. Most of them refer to aspects of Indian culture that made it into other English-speaking cultures, or things the English adopted from Indians (*shampoo* and *pyjamas* for example).

*Desi* would be an example of a more recent adoption.

> What is the equivalent to eve-teasing in AmE and BrE

"Street harassment" is a common phrase lately.

> Any anti-women connotations?

There is a connotation of blaming in using the figure *Eve*, and a connotation of the offence not being serious in use of the term *teasing*. These are both reasons for it not being adopted elsewhere, and for people opposing the use of the term in India.

Answer (score 1):

In some East Asian countries where English is spoken, *eve-teasing* is a euphemism for [public sexual harassment or molestation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_teasing).

If the act is purely vocal, the closest approximation to eve-teasing is [*cat-calling:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catcall)

> A shrill whistle or shout of disapproval made at a public meeting or performance.

A broader term that encompasses both physical and verbal harassment is [*street harassment:*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_harassment)

> Street harassment is a form of sexual harassment that consists of unwanted comments, wolf-whistles, "catcalling," and other actions by strangers in public areas.