# Usage and meaning of the word "Ragging" in India

Tags: etymology, word-usage, history, subcontinental-english

This is my first post here on an unwelcome situation in India, described by a word, "Ragging".

Wikipedia article states that:

"Ragging is a practice similar to hazing in educational institutions. The word is mainly used in India, Pakistan, Bangladesh and Sri Lanka."

With several meanings of the word "Rag",

[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rag?q=ragging#rag-2) states that it also means:

1. A programme of stunts, parades, and other entertainments organized by students to raise money for charity
   1.1 A boisterous prank or practical joke.

[Longman's Online Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rag_2):
ragging: (British English   old-fashioned) to laugh at someone or play tricks on them [= tease]

My questions are:

1. Is there any other equivalent word for "Ragging" in English?
2. (correct me if I am wrong) "Ragging" is formed from the word "Rag".
3. If anyone had ever used the word "Ragging" in UK or US (in the context  related to the meaning used in India)? (its history of usage)
4. If the word "Ragging" is British English old-fashioned, then why this word is still being used in India?

P.S. Please edit my post for punctuation and grammatical errors, if any.

Comment: Wikipedia extract covers the subject : Ragging in India: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragging_in_India

Comment: In that usage, I would expect it to be understood in the UK, but almost never used. It would be seen as hopelessly archaic, and probably indicate a very privileged person who is very out of touch with the modern world. So you could imagine someone like the prime-minister using it, but very few other people, but it would be understood.

Comment: For all those saying that it's unknown in the UK, [most university's use rag still](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rag_%28student_society%29), though the meaning may be slightly lost. That's approximately 2.3m people in the UK who hear "rag" in almost this context on a regular basis, and millions more who will remember.

Comment: Bullying = Ragging , similar to ragging i think so.

Comment: Our university certainly used to have a "Rag Week" where students used to play lots of pranks on lecturers. I believe you could pay some money to get beer delivered to class too and you would be permitted to drink it during this week.

Comment: Many regions in the US still use "ragging" in this way, usually in the form of, "Quit ragging on your brother!" or the like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ragging is the present participle of verb ([rag- to scold](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rag&allowed_in_frame=0)). 
[*Ragging*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ragging) is similar to but not the same as [*hazing*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hazing%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=).

**Ragging** in India is synonymous with **bullying**, the act of intimidating someone.

**Why** it is being used in India =>
While ragging may indeed have started out as a term for teasing (*British*- to play rough/boisterous practical joke on sb).

> Constantly and gradually the Standard Englsih usage keeps on changing, and as such certain expressions become outdated or archaic.
>   But since there's lack of direct contact with native speakers, Average InE users are generally not even aware that expressions can die too.

Ragging is now an archaic term for the native speakers (the  answers/dictionaries testifies it). It went out of style decades ago, about the time the **British left India**, but **ragging** as a synonym for bullying has **prevailed**.  Such usage is considered [**Indianism**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indianism).

[History of recorded usage-](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ragging) -(Collins dictionary)

[image]

An example of Indianism- **[Eve-teasing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221532/eve-teasing-are-such-words-used-only-in-the-country-of-origin?s=1%7C2.4782)** **~**  molestation/sexual harassment.

Comment: Just a few days ago only, I learned that the word "eve-teasing" is an example of Indianism and euphemism used in India.

Answer (score 7):

I recall back in the 70's (in the US), my friends and I using the term ragging when we meant someone was picking on / harassing us.

Answer (score 7):

The British influence is no long  all encompassing on InE. Since the teachers in India are themselves not native speakers of the language, they fail to bring in the native flavor, and the usage at times is archaic or direct translations from the native tongue.

However, if we examine the print media, the usage of terms such as eve-teasing and  ragging is rampant.

These examples are an Indian adoption of standard English.

Comment: +1 for at least attempting to explain *why* the term *ragging* prevails in India.

Comment: In India, we should be using AmE or BrE? Or, it's a subjective matter of choice? as far as I know, Indian Newspaper spell words as per BrE and government proceedings, documents too are printed in BrE.

Comment: Yes, predominantly BrE. However, the AmE is making inroads through Hollywood and the new generation is particularly more attuned to the AmE.

Answer (score 6):

I am a little confused by your question. You appear to have answered most of it yourself.

1. This is is also called *hazing*. (see your Wikipedia excerpt)
2. It is probably derived from *rag*. (see your OED excerpt)
3. The dictionary says it has been used. (see your Longman's excerpt)
4. Many English speakers in India learned from the British colonists; it's why the English accent of many Indians tends to be most similar to the British English accent.

Comment: I didn't notice it.I will make it sure next time before asking something.

Answer (score 6):

*Ragging* was a schoolboy (mostly public school) word for teasing, playing practical jokes on, and so forth (you could certainly rag a master, but care was needed). It was still in use when I was at school, but has probably died out by now in England, save for those who deliberately use archaic slang.

Answer (score 4):

1. I would expect a native English speaker to be able to work out the meaning from the context (if the writing is informal) and otherwise use the intended synonym (bullying, practical joking etc.)
2. Yes. "Ragging" is formed from the word "Rag".
3. The OED definition you gave reminded me of "Rag Week" at just about any UK university.  Basically the Student Union would organise an event lasting one week with concerts, pub crawls etc. and produce the rag magazine including the schedule, and some jokes as a way or raising money for the Student Union.  An example of a rag week stunt is a competition how far can you go from Plymouth, UK for free (Cyprus) or stopping all traffic lights and collecting money in exchange for a green light (the police came in the end). This tradition was still going strong in 1990.
4. Same reason the English use French, Indian and Latin words: living languages are dynamic and frequently adopt words from other cultures.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same when I was in grade/high school (80s/90s) in Canada, and have heard my father using 'ragging' in the same context, so we know it's been in use in the meaning of teasing, tormenting, or otherwise psychologically damaging your fellow classmates ;) for years.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, to "rag" on someone is to criticize or nag them.  This is an old term, used by my parents (who were born ca 1910).